Calculate what “X” permutation would be without permutating
So according to Chat-GPT 4, it is possible to know/calculate what a specific permutation outcome will be when you have any arrangement of numbers, by using Factoradic Representation. The only issue is Chat-GPT 4 doesn’t explain it well enough for me to understand. The problem is this:
Arrangement of numbers: 333366699
We want to calculate what the “x” (Let’s say 27th) permutation will be.
The factoradic representation ends up being 937431210 and Chat-GPT 4 says that means 369336699 is the 27th permutation! My question is how? If this is possible it would be something I would like to code so that I can skip the permutation process and just arrange the numbers by knowing what permutation they end on.

369336699 is not a permutation of 333366699, it has an extra 9 and is missing a 3?

Generally speaking, anything ChatGPT says is just words, with no particular relation to facts

You are seeking to index permutations of a multiset. This question addresses that for a lexicographic ordering, although others are possible.

What does this have to do with Python specifically?

I am trying to write a code that just tells me what x permutation is without having to wait for it to permutate x amount of times.

Anything that's "according to ChatGPT" should be considered as advisory rather than definitive

937431210 doesn't even look like a valid factoradic representation, the 9 and the 7 are too large.

You can think of this recursively, as the index of the first value in a permutation being offset by the number of sub-permutations that can be formed with the rest of the values. Add to that offset the offset of the first value within the rest of the values (and so on recursively) to get the index of a given permutation.
Going from index to and actual permutation is doing the same thing in the reverse order by figuring out which index base would the first value require and get the next value recursively with the rest.
from math import factorial
def nthPerm(values,n):
    if len(values) < 2: return values
    subCount = factorial(len(values)-1) # nb of permutations of each 1st value
    index,n  = divmod(n,subCount)       # index of first value & next n
    rest     = list(values)              
    first    = rest.pop(index)          # extract 1st value from that index
    return [first] + nthPerm(rest,n)    # recurse with the rest

Example:
from itertools import permutations
V= [3,4,5]
for i,p in enumerate(permutations(V)):
    print(i,p,nthPerm(V,i))              # actual vs computed

# 0 (3, 4, 5) [3, 4, 5]
# 1 (3, 5, 4) [3, 5, 4]
# 2 (4, 3, 5) [4, 3, 5]
# 3 (4, 5, 3) [4, 5, 3]
# 4 (5, 3, 4) [5, 3, 4]
# 5 (5, 4, 3) [5, 4, 3]

Note that this works for permutations that don't exclude repetitions produced by duplicate values in the input.  I'm not sure CHAT-GPT made that distinction clear or if it is relevant to your objective.  But, if it is, the approach would be similar but the calculations would need to be slightly different.
if you prefer an iterative solution, the same logic can be implemented without recursion:
from math import factorial
def nthPerm(values,n):
    result = []
    rest   = list(values)
    chunk  = factorial(len(values))
    for _ in values:
        chunk //= len(rest)
        index,n = divmod(n,chunk)
        result.append(rest.pop(index))
    return result

